# Documenting function call hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I am developing an extensive wrapper library. As the wrappers do not map 1-to-1 to underlying functions it would be beneficial to document the function call hierarchy.

What is the best method for achieving this? Ideally something that can be integrated into XML Comments and used to generate readable/searchable documentation. But any practical solution is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Doxygen can generate callgraphs.
[image]](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/)

Comment: This turned out to be most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sandcastle Conceptual topic has block elements which could be embedded into XML comments eg., Table, Lists. You need to enumerate the flow sequence using these elements.

Alternatively, you could generate call graphs, sequence diagrams using Architecture tools in VS2010 or other tools like NDepend and embed these images into documentation using html tags.

Comment: The first suggestion sounds like it's what I'm looking for. Can you give me a bit of a pointer? Having trouble googling the topic.

Comment: I found this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22539/Sandcastle-Conceptual-Help-Quick-Start

Comment: If you would like to create comments in code try this link about adding custom tags : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sandcastle/archive/2006/11/22/supporting-custom-tags-in-sandcastle.aspx